# Angular/node.js Stripe Checkout Integration (1 account to facilitate payments from third party payer to third party receiver)

Tags: node.js, angular, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Man, I have been at this for some days and can't find a good solution to this. I want to use my account (via public key and private key) to facilitate payments from one account to another (nothing will be going into my account). On the front-end I have:

```
  checkout(amount) {
    const strikeCheckout = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key:  environment.PRODUCTION==='true'?stripeLiveClientId:stripeTestClientId,
      locale: 'auto',
      token:  (stripeToken: any) => {
        if(stripeToken){
          console.log(stripeToken)
          this.createCharge(stripeToken,amount)
        }
      }
    });
  
    strikeCheckout.open({
      name: 'Camel Stripe',
      description: 'Stripe Checkout',
      amount: amount
    });

  }
```

Just a small snipet, but essentially this just captures the credit card and email and ensures it is a valid credit card and then makes a stripe token. I then pass this token to the node backend and do:

```
stripe.paymentIntents.create({
     amount: priceInPence,
     currency: 'usd',
     source: stripeTokenId,
     capture: false,  // note that capture: false
  }).then(charge => {
    return res.json({ success: true, message: 'Success', result: charge })
  }).catch(error => {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, status: 400, message: error });
  });
//})
};
```

No matter how I structure it, it always end's up getting the payment to my account, the account with the public/private key. Does anyone know a way I can use this token since it has the necessary information, and send the money to another account?

Answer (score 0):

You can't accept payments and move the funds into a completely different Stripe account unless you're using [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect).

Answer (score 0):

To piggy back on Paul's comment, after much research on Stripe Connect I wanted to share my findings. **Please note this is specific to my use case and is using angular/express.**

Connect offers [multi-party](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) payments, meaning you can receive funds from 1 user, then route them into another users account. You will need a stripe [connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) account. After that you connect an account, aka [create](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create) account. They offer 3 account [types](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts) all these account types need to be

1. **Custom**: basically is if you don't want the account you're routing to to see anything stripe related, meaning it is white labeled and the user has no dashboard or view of what is going on in the background.
2. **Standard**(the one I chose): this account will have a full stripe dashboard, it has all the functionality that an account would have that you make on your own. You will get a unique account id relevant to your specific connect account environment, on their end, they will have multiple account ids depending on how many other connects they are connected to, or if it is an already existing account. You will need to use this api to get the link to have them verify information before they are integrated into your connect environment [account link api](https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_links)
3. **Express**: they will have a slimmed down version of a dashboard, it is similar to standard with less functionality

At this point you're ready to start routing payments. I did angular on the front-end, here is an [example](https://www.positronx.io/how-to-integrate-stripe-card-checkout-payment-gateway-in-angular/) basically this simply creates a stripeToken, which is a verification that the card data is valid. You need to pass this to a backend to make use of it, this will not create any charges.

On the backend, I used express, you use the [charge api](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/charges-api) You pass the stripeToken as the source attribute. One important step is to add the stripe account id you see in your connected accounts dashboard. It should look similar to:

```
  stripe.charges.create({
    amount: priceInPence,
    currency: 'usd',
    source: stripeTokenId,
    capture: false,  // note that capture: false
  },{
    stripeAccount:'{{acctId}}'
  })
```

This should be sufficient to get your payments routing to the necessary account while leveraging a simple UI checkout.

One thing to note about the charges API, this is an older API and has less functionality. For my use case (US CA only with only card payments) it is sufficient. If you have a more complicated use case, or maybe your app is for heavy prod use to many users you should look into [payment intents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents).